# Excesso de EJBS no ManagedBean

Tags: java-ee, ejb, cdi

Bom dia, tenho uma dúvida quanto a forma que o Container trabalha na injeção dos EJBS será que a quantidade de EJBS injetados no ManagedBean podem interferir de forma significativa na performance da aplicação?

Answer (score 0):

Existe um cenário que sim, o desempenho de um EJB como beans de sessão stateless pode oferecer maior desempenho do que os beans de sessão stateful. Pois o stateless não mantem o estado de sessão entre o client e o bean.
Fonte: 
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=841
Espero ter ajudado.